# Materialize Multiple Select

Tags: drop-down-menu, materialize, multipleselection

I have a Materialize Multiple Select element. But I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the selected values. Does anybody know how you can retrieve the selected values?

Here's the look when you select it:
[image: Multiple Select active]

Heres how it looks when you close it:
[image: Multiple Select inactive]

But the question is how to retrieve the values inside the selector when closed.

EDIT: I am using Materialize CSS (http://materializecss.com)

Comment: Which css framework are you using? There are several and they all work differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it with basic jQuery; there's nothing special about the Material markup.

For a select like this:

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple>
    <option value="1" selected>Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

`$('#mySelect').val()` will return an array of selected values: `["1", "2"]`

Comment: Material CSS doesn't change the option elements inside the Select element. But it has a generated UL and LI elements that are changed. Those elements are generated so I can't get their ID. So that won't work.

Comment: Did you try it?  It hides the underlying select from view, but it does update the value.  Tested with 0.97.3: > $('#mySelect').val() returns null; then select something in the UI; then > $('#mySelect').val() returns ["1"]

Comment: I did try it. But it didn't work. But it seems my code had some flaws in it so i  changed it and now your code does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out: Here you shall find an appropriate way of retrieving and removing values from the multiple select. Actually materialize uses UL and LI to desplay a select. That is why it creates errors.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').material_select();
    $('select').change(function(){
        var newValuesArr = [],
        select = $(this),
        ul = select.prev();
        ul.children('li').toArray().forEach(function (li, i) {
            if ($(li).hasClass('active')) {
                newValuesArr.push(select.children('option').toArray()[i].value);
            }
        });
        select.val(newValuesArr);

        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9bL25jw9/59/

Answer (score 0):

**Try it** (get more select tag)

```
var datas = {};// object name=> value
$("form").find("select.initialized").each(function() {
    var value_input_select = $(this).parents(".select-wrapper").find("input.select-dropdown").val()
    value_input_select = value_input_select.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,"").replace(/ /gi,"")
    var value_input_select_array = value_input_select.split(",")
    var value_string = ""
    $(this).find("option").each(function(){
      if(value_input_select_array.indexOf($(this).text().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,"").replace(/ /gi,"")) >= 0){
        value_string += $(this).attr("value")+","
      }
    })
    if(value_string != ""){
      value_string = value_string.substring(0, value_string.length-1)
    }
    datas[this.name] = value_string;
  });
```

Comment: Please explain your answers. Try it doesn't help people learn